# Is there a way to get agent job taks of a pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

Im trying to get as much info as I can of a pipeline through the Azure API, is there a way to get the detail of a task? like for example I have powershell tasks, I want to get the script that runs that task, is it possible?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation does not include a REST API for getting tasks of a pipeline, but I get some REST APIs from "developer console -> Network" (F12 in most of the browers).

For YAML pipeline:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apps/hub/ms.vss-build-web.ci-designer-hub?pipelineId={pipeline id}&__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

You will get a massive response. Then you can get your yaml content in "fps->dataProviders->data->ms.vss-build-web.pipeline-editor-data-provider->content".

For classic UI pipeline:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apps/hub/ms.vss-ciworkflow.build-ci-hub?_a=edit-build-definition&id={pipeline id}&__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

You can get your tasks information in "fps->dataProviders->data->ms.vss-ciworkflow.ciworkflow.webpage.data-provider->buildDefinition->process->phases->steps".

Comment: Thank you!! this is great!!